# Configure JBOss cache to run on JBoss server 4.2.3.GA

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jboss-cache, classloader

Our commercial application used to run on different application server and letely we started adjust it to run on JBoss server.
The problem is that that application runs JBoss cache and as part of the integration with this framework, the web-inf\lib contains the follwing jars: 
**jboss-aop.jar, jbosscache-core.jar, jboss-common.jar, jboss-common-core.jar, jboss-j2ee.jar, jboss-jmx.jar, jboss-logging-spi.jar**
This causes a problem to use JNDI through the application because the jboss-common-core.jar contain naming package that cause JBoss JNDI to work incorrect.
So I need to find a way to organise my jars that on one hand jboss cache will keep working and on the other hand not to interfere to the work of JNDI

Perhaps it include moving the some or all those jars from the web-inf\lib to the /server/default/lib
Looking for someone who is familiar in this subject

(continue of this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847375/problem-configure-jboss-to-work-with-jndi3
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss appserver comes with JBossCache pre-packaged, so your webapp doesn't need to include it. If you try, then you'll get classloader problems, since JBossCache uses some pretty low-level libraries.

There is a side-effect to this problem, which is that there seems to be no way to upgrade the version of JBossCache within JBoss appserver (due to those same shared low-level libraries). JBossAS 4.2.3 ships with JBossCache 1.4.1, which is 2 generations behind the current release. I've spent quite some time trying to get around this, but I've yet to manage it, and so my apps are all stuck on 1.4.1.

Comment: It's hard to believe that there is no way to run updated jboss cache together with JBoss server. The use-case is too common- there must be solutions/work arounds to it.

Comment: @Spiderman: I would dearly love to find a workaround. I've talked to RedHat EAP support, and the man, he say "no". It seems that if you need newer version of JbossCache, you need to run AS 5+