# Compatibility between JBoss Cache to JBoss Server

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-cache

Our application runs succesfully on Tomcat, Websphere and Weblogic and as part of it uses Jboss Cache version 3.1.0.G.

Now we would like adjust our app to run also in Jboss server environment.

Is there any Jboss server version that can co-exist working together with JBoss cache of this version (3.1)?
I couldn't find a match in a compatibility matrix that Jboss publish here: 
http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/compatibility.html

Related issue ([Configure JBOss cache to run on JBoss server 4.2.3.GA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849036/configure-jboss-cache-to-run-on-jboss-server-4-2-3-ga))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [compatibility matrix](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/compatibility.html) it seems that you need at least JBoss 5.1.GA, since the 5.0 is listed to be compatible with 3.0.1. I just checked our JBoss 5.1.0.GA and it indeed features JBoss Cache 3.1.0.GA.

Comment: Can you reference to an official Jboss documentation where it said so (that JBosss 5.1.0.GA compatible with JBoss Cache 3.1.0.GA)?

Comment: Well - in the jar-versions.xml of the JBoss 5.1.0.GA distribution the version of jboss-cache bundled with the server is listed as 3.1.0.GA. It doesn't get any more official than that...

Comment: I found the file that you were talking about. Didn't know that it exist. You already deserve accepting your answer but one more question to understand - do you know about backward compatibility, meaning if for example JBoss 6.x support Jboss cache 3.3 will it support also Jboss cache 3.1 or not necessarily?

Comment: Most likely it won't support it. Many of the components are heavily coupled with one another and work only against specific version of other jars. This is the curse of enterprise application containers...